# While Click on custom module getting an error "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page"

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom module whenever I click on it, I am facing the “Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page” error. I have google regarding this error and I have found the solution to increasing the value of max_input_vars PHP configurable variable. I have increased this value but the problem is not solved.
Current PHP configurable variables are: max_input_time : 3600 max_input_vars : 200000 memory_limit : 2G

Here is my Code Hierarchy

[image]

I'm facing the error:
[image]
Controller/Adminhtml/Create/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Comlitix\ComlitixInfo\Controller\Create;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

/**
 * Class Index
 */
class Index extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    const MENU_ID = 'Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::rules';

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Load the page defined in view/adminhtml/layout/rules_create_index.xml
     *
     * @return Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu(static::MENU_ID);
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Hello World'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
[![<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::comlitix" title="Comlitix" module="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo" sortOrder="30" resource="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::comlitix"/>
        <add id="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::rules" title="Tracking Rules" module="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo" sortOrder="10" action="rules/create/index" resource="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::rules" parent="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::comlitix"/>
        <add id="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::reports" title="Report" module="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo" sortOrder="20" parent="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::comlitix" action="rules/create/index" resource="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::reports"/>
    </menu>
</config>][2]][2]
```

etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="rules" frontName="rules">
            <module name="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

view/adminhtml/layout/rules_create_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::rules.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

view/adminhtml/templates/rules.phtml

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Menu.xml {action URL}

> action="rules/create/index"

Anyone, please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: '<?php
namespace Comlitix\ComlitixInfo\Controller\Adminhtml\Create;
/**
 * Class Index
 */
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo 'Its working';
        return $resultPage = $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}'

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue mainly occurs due to URL so you have to first validate the URL of the menu

But in the current case, the controller Namespace is wrong in the file `Controller/Adminhtml/Create/Index.php` so this can also create the same issue

it should be

```php
namespace Comlitix\ComlitixInfo\Controller\Adminhtml\Create;
```

Now we refer the URL frontname which is `rules` define in the file `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`

Now based on that in the admin area you can change the URL in the `etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::comlitix" title="Comlitix" module="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo" sortOrder="30" resource="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::comlitix"/>
        <add id="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::rules" title="Tracking Rules" module="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo" sortOrder="10" action="rules/create/index" resource="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::rules" parent="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::comlitix"/>
        <add id="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::reports" title="Report" module="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo" sortOrder="20" parent="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::comlitix" action="rules/create/index" resource="Comlitix_ComlitixInfo::reports"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```